# Finding the probability of a Markov Chain.

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

> If $(X_n)_{n≥0}$ is a Markov chain on $S = {1, 2, 3}$ with initial
>   distribution $α = (1/2, 1/2, 0)$ and transition matrix
>
> $  \begin{bmatrix}  1/2&0&1/2\\  0&1/2&1/2\\  1/2&1/2&0  \end{bmatrix}, $
>
> then $P(X_2 = 2) = ?$.

**My solution:**

$X_1 = \begin{bmatrix}  1/2&1/2&0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1/2&0&1/2\\  0&1/2&1/2\\  1/2&1/2&0  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  1/4&1/4&1/2 \end{bmatrix}$

$X_2 = \begin{bmatrix}  1/4&1/4&1/2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1/2&0&1/2\\  0&1/2&1/2\\  1/2&1/2&0  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  3/8&3/8&1/4 \end{bmatrix}$

So, $P(X_2=2) = 3/8$

---

Is this solution correct?

Why or why not?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @Math1000, why is it correct?